# Парсинг более сложной страницы // requests python

Tags: python, парсер, requests

Я осваиваю парсинг страницы на python и столкнулся с проблемой при парсинге на более сложном сайте, чем статический. Пример: https://arizona-rp.com/mon/fraction/4/20
Выводит ошибку: Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page.
Что делать?
Код достаточно прост

```
post = requests.post('https://arizona-rp.com/mon/fraction/4/20', cookies=cookies)
html = BS(post.content, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: нужно обойти DDoS Protection...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47244257/python-requests-website-asks-to-please-turn-javascript-on-and-reload-the-page?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: `Selenium`, поищите вопросы с ним тут

Answer (score 0):

Вот готовый код для получения нужной страницы без использования splash и selenium.
Для его работы нужно будет установить beautifulSoup, PyQt5 и PyQtWebEngine  для его работы.
А дальше просто распарсить полученные данные с помощью инструментов beautifulSoup.

```
import bs4 as bs
import sys
import urllib.request
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl

class Page(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.html = ''
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _on_load_finished(self):
        self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)
        print('Load finished')

    def Callable(self, html_str):
        self.html = html_str
        self.app.quit()


def main():
    page = Page('https://arizona-rp.com/mon/fraction/4/20')
    """
    В объект soup получаем html с которым дальше можно работать 
    стандартными способами (поиск элементов с xpath и т.д)
    """
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page.html, 'html.parser')
    with open('parsed_page.html', 'w') as f: # Для примера можно записать полученные данные в файл
        print(soup)
        f.write(str(soup.encode('utf-8')))

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```